# Generating Pascal's Triangle in C99

Tags: c, programming-challenge, c99

I recently completed the [Pascal's Triangle](https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/) challenge on leetcode. I would like to have my code reviewed.

You don't need a leetcode account to see the description of the challenge linked above, but for completeness I'm pasting the description here.

> Given an integer numRows, return the first numRows of Pascal's triangle.
>
> In Pascal's triangle, each number is the sum of the two numbers directly above it as shown:
>
> [image: Pascal's triangle]

I think your review should touch the following points:

- Code correctness (the code passed all leetcode tests, but there might be some bug/UB hiding somewhere that neither I nor leetcode caught)
- Code performance (algorithm and implementation details)
- Code quality (the so-called "best practices" -- it's okay to be subjective)
- Stick to C99 without compiler extensions or anything non-standard

I encourage you to be pedantic about UB, memory management, adherence to the C standard, etc.

One last note: Leetcode forces me to use this exact function signature

```c
int **generate(int numRows, int *returnSize, int **returnColumnSizes);
```

So that's something I can't change.

Finally, here's my code:

```c
// solution.c

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int **generate(int numRows, int *returnSize, int **returnColumnSizes)
{
    int **ret = malloc((size_t)numRows * sizeof(int *));
    *returnColumnSizes = malloc((size_t)numRows * sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = numRows;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numRows; i += 1)
    {
        size_t size = i + 1;
        (*returnColumnSizes)[i] = (int)size;
        ret[i] = malloc((size_t)size * sizeof(int));
        ret[i][0] = 1;
        ret[i][i] = 1;

        for (size_t j = 1; j < i; j += 1)
        {
            ret[i][j] = ret[i - 1][j - 1] + ret[i - 1][j];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Here's the driver code I used to test it:

```c
// main.c

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int **generate(int numRows, int *returnSize, int **returnColumnSizes);

int main()
{
    int *returnColumnSizes;
    int returnSize;

    int **rows = generate(5, &returnSize, &returnColumnSizes);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < returnSize; i += 1)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < returnColumnSizes[i]; j += 1)
        {
            printf("%d ", rows[i][j]);
        }

        free(rows[i]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    free(rows);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's how I compile and run the code:

```bash
# run.sh

CC="clang"
CFLAGS="-std=c99 -Werror -Wall -Wpedantic -Wconversion"

$CC $CFLAGS ./solution.c ./main.c -o ./main && ./main
```

```bash
./run.sh
```

Comment: C99 is pretty ancient now, so that seems a strange requirement.

Answer (score 6):

> pedantic about UB, memory management, adherence to the C standard, etc.

Be careful about requesting *pedantic*, lots of corners.

**Consider enabling more warnings**

```
// -Wall -Wpedantic -Wconversion
-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wformat
```

**`int` overflow is UB**

Test for potential overflow.

```
// ret[i][j] = ret[i - 1][j - 1] + ret[i - 1][j];
if (ret[i - 1][j - 1] > INT_MAX - ret[i - 1][j]) {
  // Handle overflow with TBD code.
  // Maybe free allocations and return NULL
  return NULL;
}
ret[i][j] = ret[i - 1][j - 1] + ret[i - 1][j];
```

**Missing range test**

If `numRows < 0`, code has troubles.  Better to detect.

```
if (numRows < 0) return NULL;
```

Code may also want to reject `numRows == 0`, yet robust code would elegantly handle this case.

**Missing allocation test**

Allocation failed to check for success before using the pointer.

```
int **ret = malloc((size_t)numRows * sizeof(int *));

// Add
if (ret == NULL && numRows > 0) {
  // TBD Error handling.
  return NULL;
}
...
ret[i] = ...
```

Driver code should check for a `NULL` return from `generate()`.

**Avoid mixing types**

`numRows` is an `int`.  Use an `int` iterator.  `++` is a common C idiom.

```
// for (size_t i = 0; i < numRows; i += 1)
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
```

This also avoids the *cast*.  Casts hint that code is doing something wrong.

```
// (*returnColumnSizes)[i] = (int)size;
(*returnColumnSizes)[i] = size;
```

**Pedantic: `size_t` may be narrower than `int`**

`(size_t)numRows` may truncate `numRows`.

Handled in next point.

**Pedantic: Detect potential overflow**

`(size_t)numRows * sizeof(int *)` may overflow.

```
// int **ret = malloc((size_t)numRows * sizeof(int *));
if (numRows < 0) return 0;
if ((unsigned) numRows > SIZE_MAX/sizeof ret[0]) return 0;
int **ret = malloc(sizeof ret[0] * (unsigned)numRows);
if (ret == NULL && numRows > 0) return 0;
```

---

Other:

**Avoid unnecessary casts**

`size` is already a `size_t`.  No need to cast it to `size_t`.

```
size_t size = i + 1;
...
// ret[i] = malloc((size_t)size * sizeof(int));
ret[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

**Allocate to the referenced data, not the type.**

Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// *returnColumnSizes = malloc((size_t)numRows * sizeof(int));
*returnColumnSizes = malloc(sizeof (*returnColumnSizes)[0] * numRows);
// or
*returnColumnSizes = malloc(sizeof returnColumnSizes[0][0] * numRows);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Advice I (Memory usage)**

For a Pascal's triangle of \$N\$ rows, your solution allocates \$N²\$ elements worth of data. You could reduce it to \$½N(N + 1)\$. (See the Alternative implementation.)

**Advice II: On `main.c`**

In `main.c`, you write:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < returnSize; i += 1)
```

Why not `i++` instead of `i += 1`? Same applies to

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < returnColumnSizes[i]; j += 1)
```

Also, what comes to naming, I suggest you rename `i` to `level` and `j` to column.

When it comes to the inner loop, you don't need

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < returnColumnSizes[i]; j += 1)
```

You could just do

```
for (size_t j = 0; j <= i; j++)
```

Finally, instead of `printf("\n")`, you could just write `puts("")`.

**Advice III: On `solution.c`**

First of all, I would split `solution.c` into two files:

- `pascals_triangle.h` which contains the solution function declaration,
- `pascals_triangle.c` which contains the solution function definition.

In `pascals_triangle.c`, I would rename `i` to `level` and `j` to `column`. Otherwise, it seems O.K.

**Alternative implementation**

Summa summarum, I thought about the following:

**`pascals_triangle.h:`**

```
#ifndef COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_FUN_PASCALS_TRIANGLE
#define COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_FUN_PASCALS_TRIANGLE

int** generate(int numRows, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes);

#endif /* COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_FUN_PASCALS_TRIANGLE */
```

**`pascals_triangle.c:`**

```
#include "pascals_triangle.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int** generate(int numRows, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes)
{
    int** pascals_triangle = malloc(sizeof(int*) * numRows);
    *returnColumnSizes = malloc(numRows * sizeof(int));
    *returnSize = numRows;

    for (int level = 0; level < numRows; level++)
    {
        int size = level + 1;
        (*returnColumnSizes)[level] = size;
        pascals_triangle[level] = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
        
        pascals_triangle[level][0] =
        pascals_triangle[level][level] = 1;

        for (int column = 1; column < level; column++)
        {
            pascals_triangle[level][column] =
                pascals_triangle[level - 1][column - 1] +
                pascals_triangle[level - 1][column];
        }
    }

    return pascals_triangle;
}
```

**`main.c:`**

```
#include "pascals_triangle.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int* returnColumnSizes;
    int returnSize;

    int** rows = generate(5, &returnSize, &returnColumnSizes);

    for (size_t level = 0; level < returnSize; level++)
    {
        for (size_t column = 0; column <= level; column++)
        {
            printf("%d ", rows[level][column]);
        }

        free(rows[level]);
        puts("");
    }

    free(rows);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Re: "instead of printf("\n"), you could just write puts("")." --> Good compilers will emit efficient code either way. Code for clarity and avoid [micro-optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).

Comment: "solution allocates N2  elements worth data" is unclear.  It looks like OP allocates more like n*n/2.